# Working on an assignment, console not displaying intended result

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, console.log

Disclaimer: I'm very new to JS

Hi all,

I'm working on a card game for the web browser and in the console I'm supposed to get the following:

```
// User flipped queen
// images/queen-of-hearts.png
// hearts
// User flipped king
// images/king-of-hearts.png
// hearts
```

The only message I'm seeing in the console is "up and running" (see the code below).

I'm also supposed to get the following pop up:

> "This page says: Sorry, try again."

After following the (pretty vague) posted instructions, browsing my course group's Slack posts, and trial and error, I haven't gotten anywhere. So I thought I'd post my code to stackoverflow to see if anyone spots something I missed or if something's in the wrong place.

Thanks! Here's the code:

```
console.log('up and running');

var cards = [

{
rank: 'queen',
suit: 'hearts',
cardImage: 'images/queen-of-hearts.png',
},

{
rank: 'queen',
suit: 'diamonds',
cardImage: 'images/queen-of-diamonds.png',
},

{
rank: 'king',
suit: 'hearts',
cardImage: 'images/king-of-hearts.png',
},

{
rank: 'king',
suit: 'diamonds',
cardImage: 'images/king-of-diamonds.png'
}

];



var cardsInPlay = [];

var flipCard = function() {
    console.log("User flipped " + cards[cardId].rank);

    console.log(cards[cardId].cardImage);
    console.log(cards[cardId].suit);

    cardsInPlay.push(cards[cardId].rank);

}


var checkForMatch = function() {
    if (cardsInPlay.length === 2) {
        if (cardsInPlay[0] === cardsInPlay[1]) {
                alert('You found a match!');
            } else {
                alert('Sorry, try again.');
    };  
};
};

checkForMatch();
```

Comment: checkForMatch() is running as soon as it's loaded and before any cards are flipped. Therefore the cardsInPlay array is empty and nothing will display.

Comment: This condition `if (cardsInPlay.length === 2)` evaluates to `false`. Also `cardId` is not defined.

Comment: Where are you calling flipCard method ?

Comment: Also how are you setting `cardId` in `cards[cardId]`, and what is it supposed to match in your `cards[]`

Answer (score 0):

@Tsardines Read the comments in the code, I hope this helps explain it a little bit

...[and just for fun](https://s.codepen.io/curthusting/debug/WdBPGL)

```js
console.log("up and running");

const cards = [
  {
    rank: "queen",
    suit: "hearts",
    cardImage: "images/queen-of-hearts.png"
  },

  {
    rank: "queen",
    suit: "diamonds",
    cardImage: "images/queen-of-diamonds.png"
  },

  {
    rank: "king",
    suit: "hearts",
    cardImage: "images/king-of-hearts.png"
  },

  {
    rank: "king",
    suit: "diamonds",
    cardImage: "images/king-of-diamonds.png"
  }
];


let cardsInPlay = [];

// I am not sure how you were building your html, so I created a quick function that wil build one out
function buildBoard() {
  // the "board" wrapper
  const board = document.getElementById("board");
  // loop through the array of cards defined above
  for (const card of cards) {
    // create a new DOM element
    const elem = document.createElement("button");
    // just for demo display purposes
    elem.innerHTML = `${card.rank} of ${card.suit}`;
    // add the click event handler
    elem.addEventListener("click", function() {
      // pass the clicked card data to `flipCard`
      flipCard(card);
    });
    // append the DOM element to the board
    board.appendChild(elem);
  }
}


// I need to know what card is clicked so I can add it's data to `cardsInPlay`
function flipCard(card) {
  console.log(card, "selected card");
  console.log("User flipped " + card.rank);
  console.log(card.cardImage);
  console.log(card.suit);
  // use unshift to push the card to the front of the array insead of the end
  cardsInPlay.unshift(card.rank);
  // ensure we remove the older selected cards so we only have 2
  if (cardsInPlay.length > 2) {
    cardsInPlay.splice(2, 1);
  }
  // call check for match to see if the remaining cardsInPlay match
  checkForMatch();
}

function checkForMatch() {
  if (cardsInPlay.length === 2) {
    if (cardsInPlay[0] === cardsInPlay[1]) {
      alert("You found a match!");
      
      // cardsInPlay = []; // uncomment to reset the game
    } else {
      alert("Sorry, try again.");
      
      // cardsInPlay = []; // uncomment to reset the game
    }
  }
};
// build the game board
buildBoard();
// no need to call `checkForMatch` on load since the `cardsInPlay` is being reset
// checkForMatch();
```

```css
#board button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="board"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

There should be else condition for your first if block and inside you can put your alert so that you can see the alert..